# Why is program crashing while recursively adding from array to queue?

Tags: c, arrays, recursion, queue

I need to generate an array filled with random numbers and then add the array members to queue from last to first. I use function `dodajURed()` to add individual numbers to the queue, and `poljeURed()` to add array members to the queue.

Since labels aren't in English, here's a quick reference guide:

cvor = node

red = queue

ulaz = front

izlaz = rear

novi = new

In the main program, I fill the array with randomly generated numbers, print the array and then call the `poljeURed()` function.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct cvor {
    int element;
    struct cvor *sljed;
} cvor; 

typedef struct {
     cvor *ulaz, *izlaz;
} Red;

void init_red(Red *red) {
    red->ulaz = NULL;
    red->izlaz = NULL;
}

int dodajURed(double broj, Red *red) {
    cvor *novi;
    if (!(novi=malloc(sizeof(cvor)))) return 0;
    novi->element = broj;
    if (!(red->izlaz)) red->izlaz = novi;
    else (red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;
    novi = red->ulaz;
    return 1;
}

int poljeURed(int polje[], int n, Red *red) {
    if (n<=0) return 1;
    if (!(dodajURed(polje[n-1], red))) return 0;
    else {
       printf("Dodan u red: %d\n", polje[n-1]);
       return poljeURed(polje, n-1, red);
    }
}

int main(void) {
   int i, polje[10];
   int broj;
   Red red;
   srand((unsigned)time(NULL));
   init_red(&red);
   for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      broj = rand() % 11;
      polje[i]=broj;
   }

   printf("Polje:  ");
   for(i=0; i<10; i++) {
      printf("%d  ", polje[i]);
   }
   printf("\n");

   if (poljeURed(polje, 10, &red)) printf("Dodavanje uspjesno");
   else printf("Dodavanje prekinuto");

   return 0;
}
```

Now, the programme successfully fills the array with random numbers and calls `poljeURed()`. The first call is successful and I get the last member of array added to queue. But then the programme just crashes on second calling (recursion). I suspect something is wrong with my recursion, but I can't put my finger on what exactly is wrong. The programme compiles nicely with GCC in cmd.

```
int poljeURed(int polje[], int n, Red *red) {
    if (n<=0) return 1;
    if (!(dodajURed(polje[n-1], red))) return 0;
    else {
       printf("Dodan u red: %d\n", polje[n-1]);
       return poljeURed(polje, n-1, red);
    }
}
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask you to put the translations directly in the code? You don't need to post your exact code, just something minimal that exposes the unexpected behavior.

Comment: I'm in a bit of hurry, but I'll try if I'll manage. I put all of the code just for context. Like I said, I think the problem lies in my recursive function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem does not lie in the recursive function. With some quick debugging test (printf's) I've found out the problem is in this line:

```
else(red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;
```

The problem is your trying to access 'ulaz' field which is filled with NULL (in init_red).
So you need to either check if 'ulaz' is NULL:

```
if((red->ulaz)!=NULL)
   (red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;
```

Or you're missing inserting the value of 'ulaz'.

If you need something else please ask.

Comment: Thanks, this worked. I'm a bit puzzled because the function in its original form worked for me in another programme (also working with queues, but input was via keyboard instead of rand), but here it didn't. I'll take a better look at it.

Comment: This `if((red->ulaz)!=NULL)(red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;` is just totally unreadable. It should be `if ((red->ulaz)!=NULL) \n (red->ulaz)->sljed = novi;` (\n meaning line break, because line break is not possible in comments.)

Comment: @MichaelWalz Well the all the code is practically unreadable (Have you seen the variables names?!!). Anyway, I've edited it to be more readable. (You could also have made an edit request).

Answer (score 0):

For starters never mix English words with words of the native language used as identifiers in a program. This makes the code entirely unclear. Use only English words as identifiers.

The function `dodajURed` is wrong.

The data member `sljed` of the allocated object pointed to by the pointer `novi` is not set to NULL.

So you have to add the following statement

```
int dodajURed(double broj, Red *red) {
    cvor *novi;
    if (!(novi=malloc(sizeof(cvor)))) return 0;
    novi->element = broj;
    novi->sljed   = NULL;
    //...
```

If the queue is empty then you need to set the data members `izlaz` and `ulaz` such a way that the both will point to the newly allocated object.

Also this statement

```
novi = red->ulaz;
```

does not make sense.

Take into account that the data member `element` has type `int` but you are trying to add to the queue values of the type `double`.

As result the function will look like

```
int dodajURed( int broj, Red *red ) 
{
    cvor *novi;

    if (!(novi=malloc(sizeof(cvor)))) return 0;

    novi->element = broj;
    novi->sljed   = NULL;

    if ( !red->izlaz ) 
    {
        red->izlaz = red->ulaz = novi;
    }
    else
    {
        red->ulaz = red->ulaz->sljed = novi;
    }

    return 1;
}
```